# How i can iterate an array multidimensional with depth == n?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have this array

```
Array
(
    [Ramo] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [mq] => 22
                    [path] => /Ramo-0
                    [branch_name] => Ramo-A
                    [contenitore] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [path] => /Ramo-0/contenitore-0
                                    [branch_name] => Cont-AA
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [path] => /Ramo-0/contenitore-1
                                    [asset] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [path] => /Ramo-0/contenitore-1/asset-0
                                                    [branch_name] => Asset-ABA
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [branch_name] => Cont-AB
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [path] => /Ramo-0/contenitore-2
                                    [branch_name] => cont-AC
                                )

                        )

                ) 
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [mq] => 98
                    [path] => /Ramo-2
                    [branch_name] => RAMO-B
                    [contenitore] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [path] => /Ramo-2/contenitore-0
                                    [asset] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [path] => /Ramo-2/contenitore-0/asset-0
                                                    [branch_name] => ASSET-BAA

                                                )

                                            [1] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [path] => /Ramo-2/contenitore-0/asset-1
                                                    [branch_name] => ASSET-BAB

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [branch_name] => CONT-BA
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [path] => /Ramo-2/contenitore-1
                                    [asset] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [path] => /Ramo-2/contenitore-1/asset-0
                                                    [branch_name] => ASSET-BB

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [branch_name] => CONT-BB
                                )

                        )

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [path] => /Ramo-3
                    [branch_name] => RAMO-C
                )

        )
)
```

i want a table with this result:

@@@
RAMO A
RAMO B
RAMO C
@@@

@@@
CONT AA RAMO A
CONT AB RAMO A
CONT BA RAMO B
CONT BB RAMO B
@@@

@@@
ASSET ABA CONT AB
ASSET BAA CONT BA
ASSET BAB CONT BA
@@@

How can I go about having that result? The elements within an array could be even more than these.
I've been stuck for days and can't find a solution to that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57234757/9636400

Comment: it's not the solution

Comment: No, but it might help you.

Comment: It might not be a copy/paste solution, but it should give you the idea on how to solve it yourself. Remember that we're here to help you sort out issue with your existing code, not to write it all for you.

Comment: Ok in fact I appreciate the help when it is given to me, only in this case it is not very helpful. So I don't see why you have to criticize. Having said that, I thank everyone anyway.